# How can I rename a value from one column based on a condition and keep any other values otherwise?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using SQL, How can I rename a value from one column based on a condition and keep any other values otherwise?

I've tried:

```
select a, b,
  case when a = 'specific value' then 'new_value'
  else a -- keep the current value for anything else
  end as c
from x;
```

> ERROR: invalid input value for enum 'new_value'

is not about update columns on database, only select statement returned

Comment: The issue is you are mixing types `enum`(the `a` value) and `text`('new_value') and you can't do that is a `CASE`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a, b,
  case when a = 'specific value' then cast('new_value' as text)
  else cast(a as text) -- keep the current value for anything else
  end as c
from x;
```